# News ticker with jquery and without use of plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a part in a website that I need to show as a news ticker.

It looks like this:

```
<div class="news">
  <span>NEWS 1</span>
  <span>NEWS 2</span>
  <span>NEWS 3</span>
</div>
```

I need a javascript code to show news repeatedly without using plugins. The idea is to show a `span` and hide the rest of `spans` and repeat with order each `n` seconds.

How can I do that ?

Comment: What is the trigger for moving to the next span?

Comment: News 1 should be show before News 2 which should be shown before News 3. And then the cycle repeats.

Comment: setTimeout and hide()/show(), what is hard about it?

Comment: @epascarello I don't know how to create an infinite cycle.

Comment: setTimeout, when you get to the end you go back to the start.

Comment: @Alex: use setInterval and show/hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this (obviously changing the interval to suit your needs, it's in milliseconds):

```
$(function() { 
    var num_stories = $('.news > span').length,
        news_interval = 1000,
        current_story = 0;

    $('.news > span:gt(0)').hide();

    window.setInterval(function() {  
        var next_story = (current_story == (num_stories - 1)) ? 0 : current_story + 1;
        $('.news > span:eq(' + current_story + ')').hide();
        $('.news > span:eq(' + next_story + ')').show();
        current_story = next_story;
    }, news_interval);
});
```

Here's a working demo > http://jsfiddle.net/J35Sa/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
$(function() {
    var $items = $('div.news > span').hide();
    var curIndex = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        $items.hide();

        curIndex++;
        if(curIndex >= $items.length) {
            curIndex = 0;
        }
        $items.eq(curIndex).show();
    }, 2000);
});
```

You can see it working in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YxbRL/

Answer (score 1):

The HTML markup for it would make more sense as a list than random spans. So I changed it.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="news">
  <li>NEWS 1</li>
  <li>NEWS 2</li>
  <li>NEWS 3</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var lis = $(".news li");
function showNext() {
  var next = lis.filter(".active").removeClass("active").next();
  if (next.length == 0) {
    next = lis.first();
  }
  next.addClass("active");
  window.setTimeout(showNext,5000);
}
showNext();
```

**CSS:**

```
.news li.active {
  display:block;
}
.news li {
  display:none
}
```

**Running Example:**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dBJAT/)